# Not deleting row in second table

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want to delete a row from the database depending on what the file name of the image is. Lets say I have 2 tables below:

```
Image Table:

ImageId  ImageFile

01       cat.png
02       dog.png
03       dog_2.png

Image_Question Table:

ImageId   SessionId   QuestionId
01        AAA              4
02        ABD              1
03        RTD              11
```

Lets say in my application I delete the file image dog_2.png, then I want it to delete the row which states dog_2.png in the Image Table (This is working fine) and be able to delete the row from the Image_Question Table where the row contains the same ImageId associated with the ImageId and ImageFile name from the Image Table (This is not working).

So for the above example the 2 tables should now look like this after deletion:

```
Image Table:

ImageId  ImageFile

01       cat.png
02       dog.png

Image_Question Table:

ImageId   SessionId   QuestionId
01        AAA              4
02        ABD              1
```

But it does not delete the row from the Image_Question Table, how can I get this row to delete?

Below is the full code where it deletes the row from the Image Table and it contains most of the code which has been setup but not fully completed on deleting a row from the Image_Question Table:

```
$image_file_name = $_GET["imagefilename"];
$img = "ImageFiles/$image_file_name";

echo "$image_file_name was Deleted";
unlink("ImageFiles/$image_file_name");

$imagedeletesql = "DELETE FROM Image WHERE ImageFile = ?";

if (!$delete = $mysqli->prepare($imagedeletesql)) {
    // Handle errors with prepare operation here
}

//Don't pass data directly to bind_param; store it in a variable
$delete->bind_param("s",$img);

$delete->execute();

if ($delete->errno) {
    // Handle query error here
}

$delete->close();

$imagequestiondeletesql = "DELETE FROM Image_Question WHERE ImageId = ?";

if (!$deleteimagequestion = $mysqli->prepare($imagequestiondeletesql)) {
    // Handle errors with prepare operation here
}

// Don't pass data directly to bind_param; store it in a variable
$deleteimagequestion->bind_param("s",....);

$deleteimagequestion->execute();

if ($deleteimagequestion->errno) {
    // Handle query error here
}

$deleteimagequestion->close();
```

Comment: Which storage engine are you using? If you're using `InnoDB`, you can add a foreign key with `ON DELETE CASCADE` (see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html), which would remove the need for you to handle this in application code.

Comment: I don't know which storage engine it is but can you show me in your answer what the code should look like if I need to use DELETE CASCADE?

Comment: If you have InnoDB, and add a foreign key with `ON DELETE CONSTRAINT`, then you could just remove all the PHP code that deletes the records from `Image_Question`, because as soon as you deleted a record from `Image`, all of its child-records would instantly be deleted as well.

Comment: So should the code in SQL (phpmyadmin) be: `ALTER TABLE Image_Question ADD FOREIGN KEY('ImageId') REFERENCES Image('ImageId') ON DELETE CASCADE` ?

Comment: Yes, exactly, except that I'm not sure about the single-quotes around `ImageId`. Backticks would be better, IMHO.

Comment: @ruakh I put the code in SQL (without the single quotes) and it accepted the code. But when I delete the row from the Image Table, it still doesn't delete the row from the Image_Question table, do I need to inclde the ON DELETE CASCADE code in the php as well?

Comment: That probably just means that you're not using InnoDB. The other MySQL storage engines, such as MyISAM, don't support foreign keys. :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `JOIN` query to delete from multiple tables in a single query. I think this sort of statement will work for you:

```
$sql = "
DELETE img, img_q
FROM Image AS img
LEFT JOIN Image_Question AS img_q
    ON img_q.ImageId = img.ImageId
WHERE img.ImageFile = ?";
```

Comment: I want to use bind_params in mysqli because it is safer, does that mean the code is like this:

`DELETE Image, Image_Question FROM Image 
INNER JOIN Image_Question 
WHERE Image.ImageId= ?
AND Image.ImageFile = ?; `
...
`$delete->bind_param("ss",Image_Question.ImageId ,$img);`